# Poisson Modeling/ Queue Theory - Reference Material

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-modeling, queueing-theory, poissons-equation

Can anyone reccomend some practical reference material related to building and implementing queueing theory models. using stochastic (prefferably Poisson) processes?

We are looking to build out a few models to play around with the standard sort of stuff: telephone calls into a switch, wait times in line for an amusement park ride, shark attacks per year, blah blah.

thanks!

-jt

Answer (score 2):

For manufacturing systems the following book might be useful.

`J.A. Buzacott and J.G. Shanthikumar, Stochastic models of manufacturing systems.`

For a more mathematical approach, these books could also be good.

`S.M. Ross, Introduction to Probability Models.`

`S.M. Ross, Stochastic Processes.`

The order of the three books more or less reflects the difficulty in terms of mathematics (low to high) and possibly how related they are to practice (high to low).